# Trying to use file upload without forms.py - 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to make a form with some data and an upload field. Django docs doesn't provide any good tutorial of doing this without forms.py. I don't want to use that.

I tried to adapt their tutorial with forms.py (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/) with my project but I'm getting an error.
"InMemoryUploadedFile' object is not callable"
I've tried searching it on google but I didn't find this error.

I obviously miss something, because when I used to do file uploads with Node I had to do more things, like setting file storage ect.
I just don't know how to handle this in django. So what am I missing and why do I get this error?

views.py

```
def incarcarecv(req):
    context = {
        'title': "title"
    }
    if req.method == 'POST':
        nume = req.POST['nume']
        prenume = req.POST['prenume']
        telefon = req.POST['telefon']
        email = req.POST['email']
        CV = req.FILES['CV']
        cvUpload = CV(solicitant = req.user, nume=nume, prenume=prenume, telefon=telefon, emailContact=email, CV=CV)        
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/incarcare-cv.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class CV(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataUploadCV = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    nume = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    prenume = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    emailContact = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    CV = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%d/%m/%Y')
    rezolvata = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.solicitant
```

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
            <div class="container container-centru">
                <h1 class="heading-contact">Incarca CV</h1>
                {% include 'partials/_alerts.html' %}
                <form action="{% url 'incarcarecv' %}" method="POST" class="form-contact"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputnume" class="email-contact">Nume</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nume" class="form-control" id="inputnume" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introdu nume">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputprenume" class="email-contact">Prenume</label>
                                <input type="text" name="prenume" class="form-control" id="inputprenume" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introdu prenume">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputtelefon" class="email-contact">Telefon</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telefon" class="form-control" id="inputtelefon" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introdu telefon">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputemail" class="email-contact">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introdu email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputcv" class="email-contact">CV</label>
                                <input type="file" name="CV" class="form-control" id="inputemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                                <input type="submit" value="Trimite" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-login-custom">
                                <input type="submit" value="Resetează câmpurile" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-reset-custom">
                        </div>                   
                </form>
            </div>              
{% endblock %}
```

Let me translate: name = last name, prenume = first name, telefon = phone.

So how can I handle files in this situation and without using forms.py? As I said, django doesn't provide any tutorial on this.

Thanks!

Comment: By writing `CV = req.FILES['CV']` you made a local variable `CV`, so in your later call `CV(..)`, you call the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you *shadow* the `CV` model, by defining a *local* variable named `CV`. Indeed, you write:

```
    CV = req.FILES['CV']
```

So in this view, `CV` does *not* refer to the model `CV`, but to the file, later you then call the constructor of the model `CV(..)`, but you thus call the file handler instead.

```
def incarcarecv(req):
    context = {
        'title': 'title'
    }
    if req.method == 'POST':
        nume = req.POST['nume']
        prenume = req.POST['prenume']
        telefon = req.POST['telefon']
        email = req.POST['email']
        cv = req.FILES['CV']
        cv_upload = CV(
            solicitant=req.user,
            nume=nume,
            prenume=prenume,
            telefon=telefon,
            emailContact=email,
        )
        cv_upload.cv.save(cv.name, cv)
        cv_upload.save()
    return render(req, '../templates/pagini/incarcare-cv.html', context)
```

You will need to `cv_upload.save()`, since otherwise you construct a `CV` object, but you did not store in in the database.

That being said, I strongly advise you to *use* a `Form`, here it looks like a simple `ModelForm` will be sufficient. A form also can validate the input, and produce errors that you can send back to the user about what is missing.

By using the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions, it is also less likely that such name clashes will occur.

You also should, in case of a successful POST request, *redirect* to a page. This is the [*Post/Redirect/Get* web development pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Otherwise in case the submission *was* successful, if you render a page, and the user refreshes the page in the browser, the browser will make the same POST request.

Comment: Great answer. I have a few questions though. First of all, what does cv_upload.cv.save(cv.name, cv) mean. After that, why do you recomand using forms? (I don't need validation btw). How can I limit the size of the file and set the extensions I want to be allowed?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: well the maximum size is a restriction, and forms can help with validation, furthermore it will remove boilerplate code like `somevar = req.POST['some_field']`, etc. and it can also help you *rendering* the form. For example the *form* field [**`FileField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) allows you to specify a `allow_empty_file` to prevent users from uploading a file, there are several validators that can verify the MIME type, size, etc..

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: furthermore you do here some validation. For example if a POST parameter is missing, then your view will crash, in case you use a `ModelForm`, you can rerender the form, and show a message that a user did not fill in a certain field.

Comment: Can you help me integrate a form.py and explain what's happening? (because I also want to learn things). I did accept=".docx,.doc,.pdf,application/msword" on the input tag for now. I don't need any validation for the file, just a size restriction and not allow the user complete the form without uploading the file. Do I still need a forms.py file? If yes, please help me do it.